# Dependencies in Makefile not properly taken into account

Tags: c++, class, include, makefile, gnu

I have some limited knowledge of GNU makefile that has failed me at the moment.

I have a class declaration file: mdfTree.h, an implementation of the class mdfTree.cpp, and a mdfTree_x.cpp file with a main where I create an object of class mdfTree and call its public functions, which in turn call some private member variables of mdfTree.

I am compiling it with the Makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings $(shell root-config --cflags --gl\
ibs)
LDFLAGS=-g $(shell root-config --ldflags)
LDLIBS=$(shell root-config --libs)

mdfTree_x: mdfTree_x.o
        g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o mdfTree_x mdfTree_x.o $(LDLIBS)

mdfTree_x.o: mdfTree_x.cpp
        g++ $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c mdfTree_x.cpp
```

mdfTree.cpp and mdfTree_x.cpp has an `#include mdfTree.h` in it. Does mdfTree_x.cpp need `#include mdfTree.cpp` as well?

I think my Makefile is wrong because a public function from class mdfTree can't see a private variable of the same class, when I try to compile. Also, when I insert a syntax error into mdfTree.h, then the compiler doesn't pick it up. How do I tell Makefile that mdfTree_x needs to use/compile mdfTree.h/.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly add all of the dependancies, in this case your executable depends on mdfTree.o having been built and mdfTree.o and mdfTree_x.o depend on mdfTree.h. Your dependancies should be like

```
mdfTree_x:mdfTree_x.o mdfTree.o
mdfTree.o:mdfTree.cpp mdfTree.h
mdfTree_x.o:mdfTree_x.cpp mdfTree.h
```

Some compilers (e.g. gnu & intel) are able to automatically list header dependancies in make format. For example this makefile will regenerate the executable when any of `mdfTree_x.cpp`, `mdfTree.cpp` or `mdfTree.h` is changed:

```
# Compiler flags...
CPPFLAGS+=-MMD -MP
mdfTree_x:mdfTree_x.o mdfTree.o
-include mdfTree_x.d mdfTree.d
```

The CPPFLAGS will create a .d file with header dependancies when compiling, the -include line will try to include these into the makefile if present (if they're not present the source file is going to be recompiled anyway, so extra dependancies don't matter). The contents of the .d file will be something like

```
mdfTree.o:mdfTree.h
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly write make rules in most cases - for instance if you have a file `foo.o` listed as a dependancy gnu make's default rules are to run

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

(and similar for other languages). Similarly linking is automatic if the executable name matches one of the object files, e.g.

```
foo:foo.o
```

will run (note CC not CXX)

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o foo foo.o $(LDLIBS)
```

Using the default rules keeps makefiles simpler, and also lets you use environment variables to set up a default compiler.

Answer (score 2):

No you need to adjust you make file to compile and link mdfTree.cpp as well.

Something like this

```
mdfTree.o: mdfTree.cpp
        g++ $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c mdfTree.cpp
```

and change the link step to

```
mdfTree_x: mdfTree_x.o mdfTree.o
        g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o mdfTree_x mdfTree_x.o mdfTree.o $(LDLIBS)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class declaration file: mdfTree.h, an implementation of the class mdfTree.cpp, and a mdfTree_x.cpp file with a main where I create an object of class mdfTree and call its public functions, which in turn call some private member variables of mdfTree.

Your program needs the capabilities defined in both mdfTree.cpp and mdfTree_x.cpp. So you need to compile both of these files, and your link needs to incorporate both mdfTree.o and mdfTree_x.o.

You could write two rules, one to compile mdfTree.cpp, another to compile mdfTree_x.cpp. This will quickly get out of hand. Be evil. *One rule to build them all, one rule to find them, one rule to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.*

```
objects = mdfTree_x.o mdfTree.o
$(objects): %.o: %.cpp
   g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Note that there is no `$(LDFLAGS)` in the above compilation rule. You shouldn't specify link options when compiling.

You need to link the objects to form the executable:

```
mdfTree_x: $(objects)
   g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Note that now you do need to specify the linker options; you're linking.

One final point before the next step: The order in which you specify the rules in a makefile in general doesn't matter. There is one exception, however. The very first rule is the default rule, the rule that will be used if you don't specify any target at all in the `make` command. It's a good idea to explicitly put a default rule near the very top of a makefile. For example, put the following somewhere near the top of your makefile, preceding any other rules:

```
default: mdfTree_x
```

> mdfTree.cpp and mdfTree_x.cpp has an #include mdfTree.h in it. Does mdfTree_x.cpp need #include mdfTree.cpp as well?

*Never* `#include` a source file. Never. Let the linker do that.

There is something missing here, however. Suppose you change mdfTree.h. You need to rebuild. The makefile so far won't do that. What's missing is a dependency on mdfTree.h. In this case, there's an easy solution to this dependency problem: Just specify the dependency.

```
$(objects): mdfTree.h
```

In general, this header dependency problem is a very hard problem. It's best not to put those header file dependencies in the makefile. Let some automated tool such as `makedepend` figure it out those dependencies for you.